# Spark Structured Streaming Print Offsets Per Batch Per Executor

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a simple job (20 executors, 8G memory each) that reads from Kafka (with 50 partitions), checkpoints to HDFS, and posts data to a HTTP endpoint (1000 events per second). I recently started to see some straggling executors which would take far longer compared to other executors. As part of investigation I was trying to rule out data skew; is there a way to print partition:offsets for executors? Or is there any other way to track why an executor maybe straggling?

I know I can implement `StreamingQueryListener` but that'll only give me partition:offsets per batch, and won't tell me which executor is processing a specific partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it printed if you have used a sink with foreach. [forEach in structured spark streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch). The open method has those details and it gets executed for every executor. so u have those details